# Johansen test: why testing for the algebraic multiplicity of 0 and not for the nullity?

Tags: time-series, matrix, linear-algebra, cointegration, eigenvalues

From what I already know about the Johansen test, it tests the rank of the VAR matrix (in error correction form) through steps testing whether every eigenvalue is signifincantly different from 0 (first the highest eigenvalue, then the second highest one and so forth), so the number of eigenvalues statistically different from 0 would give an estimation of the rank of the matrix.

I take this as if the Johansen test was establishing an implied equivalence: n. of eigenvalues disctinct from 0 = rank of the matrix, which would imply at the same time that the number of variables minus the algebraic multiplicity of 0 (number of eigenvalues not different from 0) is equal to the rank.

However, the number of eigenvalues disctinct from 0 could be lower than the rank, since the rank nullity theorem establishes a direct relationship between the nullity (geometric multiplicity of 0) and the rank, but not between the algebraic multiplicity of 0 (number of times 0 appears as an eigenvalue) and the rank, because the algebraic multiplicity of 0 can be higher than the nullity.

**Why is then the Johansen test based on the algebraic multiplicity of 0 (number of eigenvalues not different from 0) to estimate the rank of the matrix? Why not doing a test based on the geometric multiplicity (nullity) instead?**

and not less important: **wouldn't the fact that the Johansen test estimates the rank of the matrix through the algebraic multiplicity of 0 make it biased to underestimate the rank of the VAR matrix (expressed in error correction form) since the algebraic multiplicity can be higher than the nullity?**

Comment: interesting question, I don't know the answer. But regarding the bias of the test, I suspect under most sampling mechanisms and estimation procedures we can expect the algebraic and geometric multiplicities to agree wp 1, leading to zero bias from that effect.

Comment: @JohnMadden, what does *wp 1* stand for?

Comment: @JohnMadden, I assume that you mean that we can expect algebraic and geometric multiplicities to be equivalent under most sampling and estimation mechanisms? That is an interesting assertion, could deepen a bit on it?